# ng-click doesn't work on anchor element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

Q1: I tried to use **nav** in **bootstrap** to make a **navigation bar** and bound **ng-click** to the anchors.
However `after I click` the anchor link,there is nothing happened.

Q2: I've noticed that the `anchor link` `clicked won't be active by setting bg-color` to it? How can this be implemented?

Here is the [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvy37/)...

```
<div ng-controller="SuiteSectionCtrl">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">All Suites</a>
    </li>
    <li><a ng-click="handleClick">Suite1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Suite2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Suite3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: @hgoebl I've attached the jsfiddle link

Comment: So many errors in your Fiddle. Correct those and re-post the link

Comment: @chandu I've updated the JSfiddle and add jquery lib in it but there is still one error in js. Could you help me to take a look why?

Comment: hi @Chunk, I have updated the code. checkout the fiddle

Comment: Anchor tags should only ever be used for linking, if you are using this tag solely to fire a JavaScript function this tag should be a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering Q2:

Maybe there are smarter solutions, but this one works as well:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope',
    function ($scope, $location, $rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
            var path = $location.path();
            // you may apply logic on the path (group together in case of dropdown-menu e.g.)
            $scope.topMenu = path;
        });
    }
]);
```

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"
     ng-controller="MenuCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- ... -->
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ng-class="{active: topMenu == '/'}">
                    <a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li ng-class="{active: topMenu == '/about'}">
                    <a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <!-- more... -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's a good solution...But I am trying to build a single page application which has no url redirection.
I got another solution for Q2 that you can put a data-toggle='pill' attribute in the anchor.

Comment: The code comes from a pure single page application. There is no redirection (page reload), it is all handled by AngularJS `$routeProvider` router and in most cases you don't have to place `ng-click` handlers - it's done by changing the route (#hash).

Comment: Currently,I use ng-include and ng-swith to dynamically include and replace the web page. Could you tell me which way is better? I mean ng-include and $routeProvider

Comment: Are there any reasons why you can't use the "standard" way? https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: Why is there a hash sign in href?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but I believe that AngularJS' router automatically detects whether browser is able to handle navigation via hash-change or path-change (HTML5). In your code, you only have to deal with path changes.

Answer (score 2):

The brackets for function invocation are missing. You should have:

```
ng-click="handleClick()"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Updated your code. Add `ng-app` `directive` to your `body` tag. And In your html change `ng-click="handleClick"` to `ng-click="handleClick()"`

```
<body ng-app="app"><div ng-controller="SuiteSectionCtrl">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">All Suites</a>
        </li>
        <li><a ng-click="handleClick()">Suite1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Suite2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Suite3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div></body>
```

and our `JS` code is

```
var executionAPP = angular.module('app',[])//register your app 
executionAPP.controller('SuiteSectionCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

    $scope.oneAtATime = true;

    $scope.testSuites = [{title:"TestSuite1",content:"TestContent1"},
                         {title:"TestSuite2",content:"TestContent2"},
                         {title:"TestSuite3",content:"TestContent3"},
                         {title:"TestSuite4",content:"TestContent4"},
                         {title:"TestSuite5",content:"TestContent5"}];
    $scope.handleClick = function(){
        alert('Accordion clicked');
    };

}]);
```

[Updated Fiddle...](http://jsfiddle.net/wvy37/13/)